browser refreshToken cookie is being deleted when reload the react page
I have an issue. I'm using the MERN stack technology to develop an application. When I log in, I set the refreshToken to the browser cookie. It's perfectly set in the cookie.
But the issue is when I reload the React page, the refresh token is gone. What's the issue here?


how can i fix the cookie delete issue. i need an assist.

If you enter inspection tools in your browser, and open "Applications", can you see that the cookie is set as expected för your application? Can you see when it's deleted? If you monitor network traffic, can you see when the cookie is set from response headers? Can you see a response when you reload the page that perhaps clear the cookie?

It looks to me like your isuue is that you are using SameSite=none, which requires an HTTPS connection (and the Secure cookie property), but using an HTTP connection for development. That will cause the cookie to be dropped.
You should fix it by using SameSite=strict, which provides the most secure cookies to your app, with best protection against Cross Site Request Forgery.
Note that SameSite=none is only used by identity systems, so that they can issue third-party cookies that are used for login and single sign-on. Browsers only allow these in a very limited manner, during top level redirects.
